# How do you see an error's backtrace when using SNAFU?

Tags: error-handling, rust, backtrace

How do I get `Backtrace` working with SNAFU? I tried, but I just get empty backtraces. The documentation is sparse on that it seems.

```
return Error::SampleError {
    msg: "foo".to_string(),
    backtrace: Backtrace::generate(),
};
```

prints

```
SampleError { msg: "foo", backtrace: Backtrace(()) }
```

This is being thrown from a function that is very deep in the call stack.

Comment: I don't think you need to call backtrace yourselft

Answer (score 6):

Let's start with this [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
use snafu::Snafu;

#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
enum Error {
    SampleError { msg: String },
}

type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

fn alpha() -> Result<()> {
    beta()
}

fn beta() -> Result<()> {
    gamma()
}

fn gamma() -> Result<()> {
    SampleError { msg: "foo" }.fail()
}
```

Note that it uses the *context selector* `SampleError` and the method `fail` instead of directly using the enum variant to construct the error.

Now we import `snafu::Backtrace` and add it to our error, naming it `backtrace` (see [controlling backtraces](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.6.3/snafu/guide/attributes/index.html#controlling-backtraces) if you must call it something else).

```
use snafu::{Snafu, Backtrace};

#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
enum Error {
    SampleError { msg: String, backtrace: Backtrace },
}
```

If this were a library, that's where you should stop. Your error now will *optionally* have a backtrace enabled if the **binary** decides that backtraces are worth it. This is done as backtraces aren't yet stabilized in Rust, so SNAFU has to be compatible with multiple possible implementations.

If you are controlling the binary, you will need to decide how the backtraces will be implemented. There are three main implementations selected by a feature flag:

- `backtraces` — Provides an opaque `Backtrace` type
- `backtraces-impl-backtrace-crate` — uses the third-party [backtrace](https://crates.io/crates/backtrace) crate. `snafu::Backtrace` is just an alias to `backtrace::Backtrace`.
- `unstable-backtraces-impl-std` — uses the unstable standard library `Backtrace`. `snafu::Backtrace` is just an alias to `std::backtrace::Backtrace`.

Once you've picked an implementation feature flag, add it to your Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
snafu = { version = "0.6.3", features = ["backtraces"] }
```

Then, you will need to handle the error somewhere high up in your program and get the backtrace and print it out. This uses the `ErrorCompat` trait, which I encourage you to use in a verbose manner so it's easier to remove it later, when it's stabilized in the standard library:

```
use snafu::ErrorCompat;

fn main() {
    if let Err(e) = alpha() {
        if let Some(bt) = ErrorCompat::backtrace(&e) {
            println!("{:?}", bt);
        }
    }
}
```

```
   0: backtrace::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized
   1: backtrace::backtrace::trace
   2: backtrace::capture::Backtrace::create
   3: backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new
   4: <backtrace::capture::Backtrace as snafu::GenerateBacktrace>::generate
   5: so::SampleError<__T0>::fail
   6: so::gamma
   7: so::beta
   8: so::alpha
   9: so::main
  10: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
  11: std::panicking::try::do_call
  12: __rust_maybe_catch_panic
  13: std::rt::lang_start_internal
  14: std::rt::lang_start
  15: main
```

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the primary author of SNAFU.</sup>

---

You are correct that this isn't thoroughly described in [the user's guide](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.6.3/snafu/guide/index.html) and I've created [an issue to improve that](https://github.com/shepmaster/snafu/issues/220). The most relevant section is the one about [feature flags](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.6.3/snafu/guide/feature_flags/index.html).

There are multiple tests for backtraces in the SNAFU repository that you could look to:

- [backtrace-shim](https://github.com/shepmaster/snafu/tree/0.6.3/compatibility-tests/backtrace-shim)
- [backtraces-impl-backtrace-crate](https://github.com/shepmaster/snafu/tree/0.6.3/compatibility-tests/backtraces-impl-backtrace-crate)
- [backtraces-impl-std](https://github.com/shepmaster/snafu/tree/0.6.3/compatibility-tests/backtraces-impl-std)